# PF Firewall: Restrict Access to Other Ports Only for Clients with Active SSH Connections

Tags: macos, pf

I previously worked with a large organization that employed BSD for secure control over public access to their internal network. The approach involved users establishing authenticated SSH connections to their firewall servers, granting access to all other ports/IPs within the organization's network. Importantly, this isn't traditional port forwarding; rather, numerous public IPs become accessible once SSH authentication is established.

Now, I'm seeking guidance on replicating this rule with the pf firewall, both in a general context and specifically on macOS. How can I implement a similar access control mechanism using pf firewall?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: What you are describing sounds a lot like OpenBSD's [authpf](https://man.openbsd.org/authpf). I don't think it is available for macOS, assuming you mean you want to control macOS's firewall. If you mean opening ports to macOS _clients_ on an OpenBSD firewall, it should be as simple as adding a `ssh` command to the mac user's profiles.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I want and I am thrilled to know this after so many years.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing sounds a lot like OpenBSD's [authpf](https://man.openbsd.org/authpf). I don't think it is available for macOS, assuming you mean you want to control macOS's firewall. If you mean opening ports to macOS clients on an OpenBSD firewall, it should be as simple as either having the users manually login on a terminal, or automate it using SSH public keys and adding an `ssh` command to the mac user's profiles.